# Is it possible to store the password requested by webdav in .davfs2/secrets already encrypted?

Tags: security, encryption, webdav, password-store, davfs2

davfs2 allows to store user's passwords on `$.davfs2/secrets` in plain text in order to then allow the user to mount the webdav without prompting for password.

Is it possible to store the password pre-encrypted? The idea would be that the user herself type the password in an interactive script that (knowing the encrypting algorithm) convert it in encrypted form and save it on `$.davfs2/secrets`.

In this way even root would not have access (brute-force apart) to the user password.